# Android: How to build APK without dependencies

Tags: android, veracode

I'm working on scanning source code by 3rd party to finding security issues in my Android application.
So, when I submit application to 3rd party, I want submit only my source code (Not dependencies, not library).

3rd party is accept APK file only, so I'm finding the way to build my APK without any dependencies. I using gradle to build it.

In Java application, I used https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html to package but I dont know how can do it in Android.

Can we do it by command line when build application or add new profile? I dont want to break the code for scanning and revert code for release

Can I have some advies on it?

Comment: Every app for Android uses dependencies. The Android SDK is a dependency, for example.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, yah, I knew it. What I'm looking for is the solution same with what I tried in Java spring application. Example: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html

I dont know if Android can do the same way?

Comment: You could try switching your `implementation` lines in `build.gradle` to `compileOnly`. The resulting APK will not run, but it should build.

Comment: Can we do it by command line when build application or add new profile? I dont want to break the code for scanning and revert code for release

Comment: "I dont want to break the code for scanning and revert code for release" -- then I do not know of a way to achieve what you want, sorry!

Comment: isn't the "exclude" gradle command not good for what you are trying to achieve? https://tomgregory.com/how-to-exclude-gradle-dependencies/

Answer (score 0):

You can create an **Android Library** which is structurally the same as an Android app module. It can include everything needed to build an app, including source code, resource files, and an Android manifest.

However, instead of compiling into an APK that runs on a device, an Android library compiles into an **Android Archive** (AAR) file that you can use as a dependency for an Android app module.

You can share this library and then build your App APK with it as a dependency.

More info at https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library